# Is it possible to detect if camera is facing in the opposite direction the user is facing?

Tags: android, android-camera

To make more clear what I'm asking about, let's imagine we have an Android device with no front camera.

In order for the user to take a selfie, he would need make the  back camera face his face (so opposite direction of were he would be looking at.

I'd like to detect if there's some way to differentiate between the user facing the camera to the opposite direction or to the same direction.

Trying to detect if there's a face does not serve, that was just an example to make what I'm asking easier to understand, what could be captured in the photo could be an scenery, so there would be practically no way to tell where the camera was facing unless this is determined when taking it.

Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: I find your description a bit confusing. You keep talking about taking a selfie and detecting if the user is facing the camera, but then you also imply that the pictures wouldn't necessarily have to contain any faces. In that case, why does matter if the user is facing the camera?

Comment: @Michael, we need to set the exif tag Orientation (http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html) according to how the photo was taken, and for that it's neccesary to check where the phone is facing.

Comment: Well, for both front and back camera - if user is looking at it, he is always facing the opposite direction than camera... So what is the problem?

Comment: @Dusan, it's not about looking, it's about facing the same direction. Selfie thing is jut to try to make it more clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can get which camera user is using (front or back) via API.

Comment: @Dusan, it's not about getting which camera is being used, consider the phone only has back camera. Point is to know were it's facing.

Comment: Define "where it is facing" in relation to what? To the user? How is it oriented in the 3D world? Is it facing down south-west?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237174/discussion-between-user2638180-and-dusan).